# Display MrSID in NASA Worldwind

Tags: mrsid, worldwind

This question may be a little vague, but I'm not entirely sure the right question to ask here...

I have a MrSID file that I want to display in NASA worldwind. To do this, would I need to convert the MrSID region of interest to a jpg (or something else that worldwind could display)?

Comment: you should edit your question and your title. They don't explain what you want clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worldwind has now added support for mrsid and JPEG 2000.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the worldwind forum?  This [thread](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=20636&highlight=SID) looks a bit cryptic but has [Solved] on it.

I saw a few other threads that you might read.

[worldwind thread 1](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=23992&highlight=SID)

[Worldwind thread 2](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=21499)

Worldwind used to be one of my favorite mapping apps. I haven't played with it in quite a while.

Comment: Thanks. These look interesting, but it looks like they do it all offline. I'm wondering if there's a way to just dynamically create the layer on the fly...I'll post back when I find something...